# How to specify explicit python packaging dependencies in setup.py?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, setup.py

I want to create a python package `mycode`, to be installed using `pip` (`setup.py`), which has a dependency on another package `base`. To incoporate this package dependency I follow the [setup.py instructions](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#relationships-between-distributions-and-packages) and created an entry in the `setup`  function of `setup.py` which reads:

```
'requires': ['base']
```

After I have created the package with `python setup.py sdist`, I tried to install it via `pip install`, which successfully installed `mycode`, but nothing from `base`. It seems like the `requires` entry in `setup.py` was ignored.

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to specify `install_requires` instead, see [New and changed `setup` keywords](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#new-and-changed-setup-keywords).

The `requires` field was too vague and imprecise, so the `setuptools` folk (so `easy_install`, from which `pip` evolved) added more specific fields. In addition, there are `setup_requires` and `test_requires` fields for dependencies required for `setup.py` and for running tests.

Comment: Thanks that seems to work! But does this mean the documentation I have linked is not useable? Is this not part of an 'official' documentation?

Comment: `pip` follows the `setuptools` universe of packaging. The `distribute` fork of `setuptools` has [good documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/), and then there is the [Hitchhikers Guide to Packaging](https://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) too.

Comment: But, yes, the `distutils` documentation is correct for `distutils`, but `distutils` has been left behind by `setuptools`. There is / was a `distutils2` in the works to remedy that but that effort is currently stalled, I think.

Comment: Ok I might get it. As `pip` and so on (and `setup.py`) are not part of the standard python libs, or have been changed by the forementioned packages, it is outside the scope of 'standard'-python and I have to lookup at the specific sites. Python packaging is really confusing. I am waiting for distutils2 desperately...

Comment: It is, and it's a pity the `distutils2` effort has stalled. A lot of experience with the `distribute` fork went into that effort and I had high hopes for that to make it into the Python stdlib for the 3.x series.